# Mercury installed but getting error zsh: command not found: mercury

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to use [mercury](https://runmercury.com/) for making web apps from my jupyterm notebooks.

I have even installed mercury using `pip install mercury`
And it is installed as I am able to import and use it in my notebook, but when I am using the command `mercury run`
I am getting error `zsh: command not found: mercury`

Insteam of pip, I have used brew but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch the terminal in the same folder as your notebook and write the command "mercury run"in the terminal. Not in jupiter notebook.
You can also run Anaconda prompt and enter this command there